# Let $G$ be a graph of order $n=2k+1 \ge3$ for some positive integer k.

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a graph of order $n=2k+1 \ge3$ for some positive integer k. Prove that if vertices of G have exactly vertices of G have exactly the same degree as the vertices of G complement, then G has an odd number of vertices of degree k.

I am not sure exactly sure how to this question. First I know the graph has an odd number vertices because the order is $n=2k+1$. So the number of vertices is odd.

By the handshake lemma the sum of the degree of each vertex of both G and G complement is is 2t where t is the number of edges. Since the number of vertices is odd each vertex must have in G must have an even number of edges.

So each vertex must be even. But then I am stuck.

Comment: What do you mean by "then G has an odd number of degree vertices k." ?

Comment: Read again (any) text you have written before posting it : here 1) You must choose a title that is not the first sentence of your text like "A vertex degree issue dealing with a graph and its complement" 2) Are you aware that you have a "stuttering trend" in your writing ? These remarks are, in my spirit, intended to help you, not to criticize you.

Comment: Sorry I dont know why I write that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the [degree sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)#Degree_sequence) of $G$ and $\overline G$, $\mathscr D(G)$ and $\mathscr D(\overline G)$, which according to the conditions are the same sequence. Then a particular vertex will be represented in sequence at the same position from the start of  $\mathscr D(G)$ and the end of $\mathscr D(\overline G)$ and those two numbers will sum to $2k$, the degree of each vertex in $K_{2k+1}$.

Since $2k+1$ is odd, the middle value of both degree sequences must represent the degree of the same vertex, so that value must be $k$. Then each additional vertex with degree $k$ will appear either side of this middle point so there must be an even number of such in addition to the middle point, giving an odd number of degree-$k$ vertices as required.

Comment: I see so each individual vertex is k I could never think of that.

Comment: There must be one vertex with degree $k$ because it is in the middle of the degree sequence. Then if a neighbour in the sequence is also degree $k$, then the neighbour on the other side will be too - to switch with in the complement.